# Operator overload error

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, syntax-error, new-operator

I have the following code:

```
class Pudelko{
    private:
       int rozmiar;
       int* tab;

    public:       
       Pudelko(int size){
          this->rozmiar = size;
          this->tab = new int[size];       
       };
       Pudelko& operator+ (const Pudelko &P);       
};
```

And I want to overload the `+` operator:

```
Pudelko& Pudelko::operator+ (const Pudelko &P){ 
     int s = this->rozmiar > P.rozmiar? P.rozmiar: this->rozmiar;
     Pudelko* sum;
     sum = new Pudelko(s);
     for(int i=0; i<s; i++){ 
        sum->tab[i] = this->tab[i] + P.tab[i]; 
     }    
     return *sum; 
};
```

In my `main()` function:

```
Pudelko* p;
p = new Pudelko(2);  
p->wprowadz();  // set tab elements for first object

Pudelko* p1;
p1 = new Pudelko(3);
p1->wprowadz(); // set tab elements for second object


Pudelko* suma;
suma = p + p1;     // I want to add two object
suma->wypisz();   // show output tab
```

I can't do that because it gives me an Error:

```
invalid operands of types `Pudelko*' and `Pudelko*' to binary `operator+'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you `new`ing everything? This isn't Java =/

Comment: You have a memory leak in the operator function. In modern C++ there's seldom a need to use pointers. Also, the operator function should return *by value*.

Comment: I do not expect `operator+` to return a reference.

Comment: I have to return  sum instead of *sum? Do I have to do something else to run this code?

Comment: I think the "correct" code is like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e81aaa0d19a58414  Notice that I never use `new` in my code.